# images not loaded from CSS at different subdomains with nginx

Tags: css, nginx, https, path, subdomain

Some images (icons) are not loaded from CSS located on different subdomains. I see a symbol because image file is not loaded.

Our nginx server is serving https **www.mysite.com** as a reverse proxy.
The same nginx is serving https **static.mysite.com** static files like CSS, images, js, fonts, etc on

Main page at **www.mysite.com** index.html loads CSS normally like:

```
<link href=“https://static.mysite.com/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Everything load perfect (CSS, images, js, fonts…) EXCEPT icons related to some font-awesome.

I have tested and the problem is serving main **www** and **static** files on a different subdomain.

Some tests:

If I replace CSS call with public CDN recommended by font-awesome:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

It works OK

If I serve my HTML pages from same domain **static.mysite.com**,  It works OK, but as I am using a reverse proxy I should use 2 subdomains

Possible ideas:
1) serving static files and reverse proxy into the same domain / nginx block? is that possible?
2) adding some extra code to nginx blocks? (it happened to me some years ago with Apache and not fonts on firefox)

Thank you all in advance

Comment: I'm kinda confused why you don't just use the cdn...

Comment: well, I always thought that this would improve my speed and and also, because I just want to control all my files under control... but maybe you are right

Comment: That `.css` file pulls in other files form the same site. These files are specified using a relative URL. So unless you host all of the files locally, you will be missing a lot.

Comment: Let me clarify... Static and www are nginx blocks, located on same machine, but different subdomains... I need to have it like this way because I need a separate block for proxy reverse (www) and another for static files (CSS, pictures etc)